# Getting time interval between many dates in array Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, date, charts

as I mentioned in the title, I have an array of dates and I want to get the time interval between these days, the first day in this array will calculate a time interval with another date out of this array. I'm trying to represent this numbers in chart (I've used Chart library) and here is my code:

```
            var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for x in relapsesArrayInDate {
            

            if  x == relapsesArrayInDate.first  {
                
                let userPreviousStreak = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userPreviousStreak")
                let regDate = Auth.auth().currentUser!.metadata.creationDate!
                let userFirstDate = regDate.addingTimeInterval(-60*60*24*Double(userPreviousStreak+1))
               
                let firstRelapseDistance = self.calenderC.dateComponents([.day], from: userFirstDate, to: relapsesArrayInDate.first!)
                let firstRelapsePeriod = firstRelapseDistance.day!
                entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: 1.0, y: Double(firstRelapsePeriod)))

            } else {
                
                let relapseDistance = self.calenderC.dateComponents([.day], from: x , to: x - 1)
                let relapsePeriod = relapseDistance.day!
                entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(relapsesArrayInDate.firstIndex(of: x)! + 1), y: Double(relapsePeriod)))
                
            }
        }

        let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()
        let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)
        self.linearChart.data = data
```

but when I run the code that's what I get:
[image]

I hope that my issue is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like a bit of a mess.

Is relapsesArrayInDate an Array of type `[Date]`? And does it contain Dates in chronological order? If so, why are you converting your dates to day values?

The code below would give you the difference between the dates in your relapsesArrayInDate as a array of Doubles (the differences in seconds)

```
let differences = [Double]()
for index in 1 ..< relapsesArrayInDate.count {
   let start = relapsesArrayInDate[index-1].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
   let end = relapsesArrayInDate[index].timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
   differences.append(end - start)
}
```

If you wanted to you could then use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to convert your time intervals to string formats (e.g. “3 days, 7 hours, 5 minutes and 37 seconds”)

### Edit:

Ok, after some coffee I understand Leo's zip-based code. Here is a function that will take an array of increasing dates, and a starting date, and return the offsets between dates

```
func intervalsBetween(dates: [Date], startingAt start: Date) -> [TimeInterval] {
    //Create a new array that starts with the starting date
    let datesPlusStart = [start] + datesArray

    //Calculate an array of intervals between dates in datesPlusStart
    let intervals = zip(datesPlusStart.dropFirst(), datesPlusStart).map{$0.timeIntervalSince($1) }
    return intervals
}
```

You should be able to call that function, passing in dates = relapsesArrayInDate, and startingAt = `Auth.auth().currentUser!.metadata.creationDate!`

Note that if you want your starting date to be n days after the creation date, you should not add -60*60*24*Double(userPreviousStreak+1) to the creation date.

You should instead use the Calendar function `date(byAdding:value:to:wrappingComponents:)` to add n days to the starting date.

Comment: - yes the array is of [Date] and the dates are ordered by the earlier. The first date in the array need to get the difference from another date that isn't included in the array so that's maybe what makes my code looks like a mess :(

Comment: @DuncanC you can simply zip the collection dropping the first element with itself and map the tuple `let intervals = zip(dates.dropFirst(), dates).map{$1.timeIntervalSince($0) }`

Comment: @i4mjad so create a new array, append the first date, and all objects from the existing array, and then use the approach I outlined above.

Comment: @LeoDabus I am up painfully early (got paged at work) and can't wrap my head around your zip approach. Given that the OP wants to include a starting date that's not in the array, why not post your own answer using zip?